# Running dotnet ef migrations for class library gives error MSB4006

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) project targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2.

I have introduced Entity Framework into the web project and have set up and run

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial
```

from the web project directory. The migration is created, all is good.

I want to refactor the code so that my entities and db context are in a class library instead. So I have created a separate Class Library (.NET Framework) project, also targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2.

Still from the web project directory I run

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial --startup-project . --project ..\MigrationTest.Entities
```

where `MigrationTest.Entities` is my class library.

This time I get:

> C:\Projects\Experiments\MigrationTestNoIdentity\MigrationTest.Entities\obj\MigrationTest.Entities.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets(4,5):
> error MSB4006: There is a circular dependency in the target dependency
> graph involving target "GetEFProjectMetadata".
> [C:\Projects\Experiments\MigrationTestNoIdentity\MigrationTest.Entities\MigrationTest.Entities.csproj]
> Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an MSBuild-based .NET Core project. If you're using custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.

It isn't a .NET Core project, so I try creating a .NET Core project instead. Running the migrations command then gives:

> C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.3\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Common.targets(73,5):
> error : Project
> 'C:\Projects\Experiments\MigrationTestNoIdentity\MigrationTest.Entities.Core\MigrationTest.Entities.Core.csproj'
> targets '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'. It cannot be referenced by a
> project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2'.
> [C:\Projects\Experiments\MigrationTestNoIdentity\MigrationTest.Entities.Core\MigrationTest.Entities.Core.csproj]
> C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.3\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(92,5):
> error : Cannot find project info for
> 'C:\Projects\Experiments\MigrationTestNoIdentity\MigrationTest.Entities.Core\MigrationTest.Entities.Core.csproj'.
> This can indicate a missing project reference.
> [C:\Projects\Experiments\MigrationTestNoIdentity\MigrationTest.Web\MigrationTest.Web.csproj]

And of course, the Core project cannot be referenced by the .NET project.

Is what I am trying to do a supported scenario? Is there some problem with my command line usage? Something else?

Comment: If the core web project references a core class library, then all is well. Perhaps this is a limitation on .net class libraries.

Comment: Also successful with .NET Framework web app referencing a .NET Standard class library.

Comment: I guess the dotnet ef tooling doesn't support targeting a .NET Framework class library even if the referencing project is an ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework) project, despite migrations working for the web project itself. This is probably reasonable and beyond the scope of the .NET Core tooling, although a more helpful message would be good.

Comment: I am also having same problem. Were you able to figure out any solution for this?

Comment: @rout0802 See comment above.

Answer (score 6):

It's worth checking to ensure you have the EF Tools package installed.

Open the Package Manager console in Visual Studio and execute:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Then try your `dotnet ef <commands>` again.

Answer (score 3):

Super stupid, but I had to use a forward slash because I was on Mac.

So in the OP's example:

`dotnet ef migrations add Initial --startup-project . --project ../MigrationTest.Entities`

I was running the command from the project that contains the `DatabaseContext`, then the command is as follows:

`dotnet ef migrations add Initial --startup-project "../MyProject.Api"`

Comment: I had a very similar experience.  Not on Mac, I was just in the wrong folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was running the below command and it worked for me -

Project drive location is- D:\MyProjects\SourceCodeAPI\

Initial Migration

```
dotnet ef --startup-project D:\MyProjects\SourceCodeAPI\ migrations add initial
```

Create Database

```
PM> dotnet-ef --startup-project D:\MyProjects\SourceCodeAPI\  database update
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might have this issue, see @fractor's response under the original question. For me the problem was caused by having a .NET Core web app referencing a .NET Framework class library. This is a very non-intuitive error, but once you correctly create your class library targeting .NET Core this problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the in "Default Project" window  if you are targeting the expected project
   [image]
2. Check which is current directory
   [image]
3. In my case it was NOT the expected directory where was my project located, so I had to navigate to it manually. This solved my issue.