# Circular dependency creating EF migration in MAUI Blazor

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor, maui, entity-framework-migrations

### Previous research

- This is NOT a duplicate of [Running dotnet ef migrations for class library gives error MSB4006](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43620728/running-dotnet-ef-migrations-for-class-library-gives-error-msb4006) - because `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` is installed
- I have tried several permutations of the `add migration` command including the `use-context` and `startup-project` parameters
- I have executed the `add migration` command from both the `.sln` and `.csproj` folder, changing paths as appropriate

### Configuration

My project is .NET 7 scaffolded as a MAUI Blazor project using JetBrains Rider

I am only targeting windows

```
<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

I am using
EF core SQLite `v7.0.8`

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="7.0.8"
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.8"
```

Running the project in debug mode has the project start as expected and the `.db` file be created as expected
`CreateMauiApp()` contains the following

```
builder.Services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite().AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>();
using (var client = new DatabaseContext())
{
    client.Database.EnsureCreated();
    client.Database.Migrate();
}
```

`DatabaseContext` includes the following

```
public DbSet<SourceFile> SourceFiles { get; set; }

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    var dataSource = Path.Combine(@"D:\DEVELOPPMENT", "FileManager", "app.db");
    var directory = new FileInfo(dataSource).Directory;
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory?.FullName ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());
    
    var connectionStringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder {DataSource = dataSource};
    var connectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString();
    var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connection);
}
```

### The problem

When I try to create a new migration using the following

```
dotnet ef migration add Create SourceFile -s .\FileManager.App.csproj -c FileManager.App.Data.DatabaseContext
```

I get the following error

```
error MSB4006: There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph involving target "GetEFProjectMetadata".
Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an SDK-style project. If you're using a custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.
```

I have only one project `FileManager.App.csproj` in my solution `FileManager.sln`
There is no other `.csproj` present in the repository included in the `.sln`
I am NOT targeting any platform other than `windows`.

### Question

How do I create a new migration in a .NET 7 MAUI Blazor app using Entity Framework 7 and SQLite?

Comment: Searching `error MSB4006: There is a circular dependency in target dependency graph involving target "GetEFProjectMetadata"` finds: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14399. This suggests using `Add-Migration Initial -Project model -StartupProject view` instead of `dotnet ef`. [I am not familiar with EF migrationm so can't help further.]

Comment: This indeed works. I opened VS2022 and execute `Add-Migration` in the package manager console, and my new migration was created as expected. This doesn't make sense to me, as I thought `Add-Migration` and `dotnet ef migrations add` were essentially the same tool. Guess not. This is bothering me, as I can't get `Add-Migration` to run anywhere outside Visual studio, which I don't normally use ...

Comment: You could add a comment on that issue (with a link back to this SO post), stating that the same problem occurs when do `dotnet ef` for a `Maui Blazor` project. Given the discussion there, it sounds like Maui Blazor's SDK, `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">` at top of .csproj is not correctly handled by `dotnet ef`. (A non-Blazor Maui project is `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`, which is the usual dotnet SDK. )